# Как правильнее передавать многобайтные юникод-символы в json строке для записи в БД SQL?

Tags: php, sql, json

В `PHP` до версии `5.4` многобайтные символы Unicode передавались всегда в кодированном виде `\uXXXX`. Сейчас же существует константа `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` которая передает символ "как есть" - какой формат предпчтительнее для записи в БД `SQL` ? Или же это просто дело вкуса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вы будете хранить всю эту радость в БД - это дело вкуса. Передавать же JSON лучше в формате \uXXXX, так как точно нигде ничего на перекодировках не потеряете, хоть и чуть больше по объему выйдет.

Comment: И где что-то должно потеряться?

Comment: @Qwertiy не **должно**, а **может**. Если вы не знаете, то задайте вопрос - сверху, справа страницы кнопка есть.